# Wait until tasks are finished with Ray in Python

Tags: python, ray

I have a script that looks like this:

```
my_dict = {}

@ray.remote
def f(n):
    # adds to my_dict after parsing through a 
    # large file that was split up into 8 sections;
    # each section is parsed in parallel using ray

tasks = [f.remote(i) for i in range(1,9)]
ray.get(tasks) 

with open('my_csv.csv', 'w+') as write_obj: 
    # write rows from my_dict keys & values
```

In order for my_csv.csv to look correct, the tasks must finish adding to my_dict. These tasks are counting columns in my_csv and adding them to certain values of my_dict. As soon as the tasks start running, however, my_csv is opened and written to with unfinished values. How can I stop my code from running until the tasks are finished? Is there a way to do this with ray?

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you run ray tasks, they are running in a different process. That says, `my_dict` wouldn't be shared!

The right solution here is to use an actor. Actor is a stateful process.

```py
@ray.remote
class MyDict:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_dict = {}
    
    def insert(key, value):
        self.my_dict[key] = value

my_dict_handle = MyDict.remote()

@ray.remote
def f(n, my_dict_handle):
    # do something and get key, value for my dict
    my_dict_handle.insert.remote(key, value)

...
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I do need to add to the preexisting value (i.e. my_dict[key] + 1), so how can I accomplish this using this method?